How many Wiggenweld Potions can I carry on me?
I want to try and see how many Wiggenweld Potions I can collect.
I'm currently carrying 16 Wiggenweld Potions on me:

Is there a limit to how many I can carry on me or can I carry as many as I can find?
If there is a limit as to how many I can carry, is this a hard limit? Meaning can I upgrade or carry more later in the game?

Yo the maximum number of Wiggenweld Potions you can carry is initially limited to 25. And you cannot carry more than this at any given time, regardless of upgrades or progress in the game.
Once you reach the limit of 25, any additional potions you find or craft will not be added to your inventory.
